# Embedding a Google map in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3

I'm confused as to where exactly place the script tags in my Rails app to have a Google map embed in a page.  I'm following the directions from the Google API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAK04aYSxZArPElFFZfo3o2p-CbviPzfhc&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm placing the first script tag within my `application.html.erb` file like so:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAK04aYSxZArPElFFZfo3o2p-CbviPzfhc&sensor=false" %>
```

I have a Venue model and a venues controller.
I want the map to appear in the Venues show action.  So I place the second script inside `venue.js`.  My `show.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<div class="center">
  <h1><%= @venue.name %></h1>
  <address><%= @address %></address>
  <div id="map-canvas"/>
</div>
```

But no map appears when I load this page.

Comment: use "view source" in the browser to see if the javascript code is loaded OK. Also use the javascript console to check for errors.

Comment: When I inspect `#map-canvas` in my Rails app it contains the same javascript as my standalone html tutorial page.  But the map doesn't display.

Comment: Figured it out.  Need to specify a width and a height for `#map-canvas`.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to do this is to simply embed the map in an iframe. Using .haml for markup,

```
%iframe.google-location{ frameborder: '0', scrolling: 'no', src: 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:{google_generated_placeId}' }
```

the class 'google-location' (or whatever you want to name it) only needs to have the size of the iframe.

(make sure to have a valid api key)